# How to show an item's context in a hierarchy

Tags: navigation, hierarchy, breadcrumbs, context-sensitive-help

I'm trying to figure out a way to allow contextual navigation to nearby items in a large hierarchy. For example, say my hierarchy is countries, states, counties and citites.

When viewing a county, you should be able to navigate up a level to the state, or down a level to one of the cities in that county.

Breadcrumbs are an established UI that takes care of the *up* direction of this problem:

> **USA**   —>  **California**   —>  **Los Angeles County**

But it wouldn't make sense to put all the cities in LA county into a breadcrumb trail. I was thinking of a vertical layout with the containing item above, and the contained items below, but it makes it difficult to know which one is the "current" item.

[image]

Plus, as you can see, it quickly gets out of hand if there are a lot of sub-items (especially if they have long names), and will look empty if there are very few.

Answer (score 2):

An idea - did you consider putting dropdown menus into the breadcrumbs?

It could look like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuN5M4.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: I think the breadcrumbs convention is that the last item is the current item. Violating that convention seems too confusing. You > Are > Here > Not here